# ArrayStoreException when trying to shuffle elements of jobjectArray in c++

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm currently writing an android game and part of the AI requires an array of Java objects to be cloned and shuffled a lot of times. I'm trying to bring this operation to the native layer to see if this yields any performance gain. I'm keeping the array of objects as a field in my Java class and am accessing it in the JNI layer as such.
I'm very new to JNI and native programming so I'm pretty much stuck already. 
Here's some of the relevant JNI code in a .cpp file:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_my_class_MyArrayClass_shuffleArray (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){

   jfieldID objectArrayID;
   jfieldID objectArraySizeID;

   jobject objectArrayObject;
   jobjectArray objectArray;
   int objectArraySize;

   /* Get a reference to obj’s class */
   jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);

   /* Look for the instance fields in cls */
   objectArrayID = env->GetFieldID(cls, "objectArray","[Lcom/my/class/MyClass;");
   objectArraySizeID = env->GetFieldID(cls, "objectArraySize", "I");

   /* Read the instance fields */
   objectArrayObject = env->GetObjectField(obj, objectArrayID);
   objectArraySize= env->GetIntField(obj, objectArraySizeID);

   /* Cast objectArray Object to jobjectArray */
   objectArray = reinterpret_cast<jobjectArray>(&objectArrayObject);

   /* Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle */
   for (int i = objectArraySize- 1; i > 0; i-- ) {

       int index = rand() % i + 1;

       jobject tempObj = env->GetObjectArrayElement(objectArray, index);
       jobject tempObj2 = env->GetObjectArrayElement(objectArray, i);

       env->SetObjectArrayElement(objectArray, i, tempObj);
       env->SetObjectArrayElement(objectArray, index, tempObj2);

   }
   env->SetObjectField(obj, objectArrayID, objectArrayObject);
}
```

The code compiles fine without errors, but upon calling the native method I get the following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(31021): java.lang.ArrayStoreException: (ƓB cannot be stored in an array of type ߒB
```

Apparantly the array doesn't want to accept one if it's own elements because it is of a different type, which doesn't make a lot of sense, so obviously I'm missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `The code compiles fine without errors`  Which only means the there are no syntax errors.  Doesn't determine if the program will run correctly.  Second, have you tried to write the swapping routine in a small Java function and see if Java allows you to swap elements like that?  If not, then I highly doubt JNI will let you get away with it.

Comment: Yes, this swapping routine works just fine in Java but it's a completely different syntax of course. I would provide a small example but I can't seem to create a code block in this comment section. 
I think that the problem has to do with the typing of either the jobjecArray or the jobject. It seems a lot harder to type objects in JNI than it is in Java.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<jobjectArray>(&objectArrayObject);` <-- Why the `&`? A `jobject` and a `jobjectArray` are both pointers.

Comment: Why do you think a shuffle operation would be faster in native?  With runtime compilation/optimization, you're more likely to be faster in pure Java.  You'd also be better off passing in the array and its length as explicit parameters, rather than looking them up once you're in native code.

Comment: @Michael Honestly, I have no idea :) I'm also new to c++. I found this example somewhere on the internet as I also didn't know a cast to jobjectArray was necessary. Should I omit the & ?

Comment: The cast is superfluous (and incorrect).  You should be able to use the `objectArrayObject` directly.

Comment: It certainly looks like that `&` should be removed.

Comment: @technomage I read a paper on a similar AI that was developed for the android platform. In it was stated that the the cloning and randomizing of the arrays holding the game objects was the bottleneck. They claimed to have noted an increase in performance after moving these operations to the native layer. So I thought the only way to be sure was to try it out myself. 
The looking up of the objects would have to be done only once as there is caching technique that can be used but you're right, I could pass them as parameters.

Comment: @technomage if I use the objectArrayObject directly, the **GetObjectArrayElement** function gives following error: `Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
_jobject * GetObjectArrayElement(_jobjectArray *, int).` 
If I try to read in the jobjectArray directly using **objectArray = env->GetObjectField(obj, objectArrayID);** I get `invalid conversion from 'jobject {aka _jobject*}' to 'jobjectArray {aka _jobjectArray*}' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @Michael I omitted the `&` and everything works now! I am the proud owner of a shuffled object array :) So it does seem the cast to jobjectArray is necessary, or at least not faulty, as **env->GetObjectField(obj, objectArrayID);** returns a jobject and not a jobjectArray. Thanks everybody for your input!